# Finding the optimal number of clusters from Dendrogram

Tags: python, cluster-analysis, hierarchical-clustering, dendrogram

I am using a dendrogram to visualise the number of clusters formed by a dataset of phrases. I'm using -

```
from scipy.cluster.hierarchy import dendrogram, linkage
Z = linkage(X.todense(), 'ward')
dn = hierarchy.dendrogram(Z)
plt.axhline(y=2, color='r', linestyle='--')
plt.title('Dendrogram')
plt.ylabel('Distance')
plt.show()
```

How can I count the number of clusters being formed at a particular 'y' from the dendrogram? For eg. I'd like to find out and compare the number of clusters at `y=2` and `y=1.5`.

Also, is there a relationship between the y (distance between clusters) and the optimal number of clusters, as in the case of K-Means Clustering (something analogous to Elbow Method, Silhouette Method)?